# How to make a click or double click on a word on a web page to trigger an event handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, dhtml

For a page like

http://www.answers.com

if the user double clicks on any word in the page, a pop up box will show up and shows the definition for that word.

I can think of a way to use DOM scripting to break up all words in the page and then make each of them go under a separate "span" element... but otherwise isn't it true that if all the text is under a "p" element, then the "p" element node get triggered to handle the double click event, but there is no easy way of telling which word is clicked on?

Comment: Good question, neat functionality, will be watching this question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You simply add a double click event to the entire document, like so:

```
function get_selection() {
    var txt = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        txt = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        txt = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return txt;
}

$(document).dblclick(function(e) {
    var t = get_selection();
    alert(t);
});
```

If you only wanted this to work on select paragraphs, you would change the selector to `p.myclass` or something like that. This hinges on the fact double clicking a word highlights it in browsers. Not really sure if it's exactly how answers.com does it, to be honest.

Comment: Beat me a few minutes. I was about to suggest the same thing. +1

Comment: Sorry, the problem was that the user defined getSelection function is clobbering window.getSelection. An easy fix is just renaming the user defined function.

Comment: Could you explain the need for the two else if conditions? I'm guessing this sort of thing is handled differently by different browsers, is that the case?

Comment: @misterMatt Yes, the function covers all the ways in which one would get the selected text in different browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go, a blog article that describes how you do this using jQuery. His test implementation is similar to what you want. Namely double clicking a word pulls up the definition from a dictionary:

[Using jQuery and Double clicks to get data](http://web.archive.org/web/20090202031620/http://www.dumpsterdoggy.com/articles/?combine-jquery-and-double-clicks-to-get-data)